# Center a floating button between two floating buttons (liquid dimensions)

Tags: css, button, css-float, center, liquid

I'm having issues centering a floating button between two other floating buttons.

It looks like this thus far:

[image: jQuery buttons; need to center Button B]

The CSS is pretty basic at this point:

```
A {
  float: left;
}
B {
  float: left;
}
C {
  float: right;
}
```

Note: Button A is positioned to the left-most extreme on a page and Button C is the right-most.  B should be in the middle (that's the idea, anyway).

I know there is no 'center' value for float.  And I have read some other solutions for this problem.  But most of them involve setting a specific width in a wrapper div, which not an ideal solution, imo, for a liquid layout design.  If you have to wrap the button, I'm not sure how that's any better than using straight positioning.

Either way, I'm looking for a solution using a liquid layout approach.

I also tried the following but it did not work.

```
B {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Comment: The A and B buttons look correct the way they are; is it your intention to put the B button in the middle?  I don't think that will look right. Why not just float the C button left?

Comment: Yes, thank you. My intention is to put the B button in the middle.  I should've specified that the image above is a width of a page.  Please allow me to redo it.

Comment: I think my answer is going to be the same; you should put your buttons in their own div, and float them all to the left.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on that, Robert Harvey?

Comment: How's your markup? 3 simple elements wrapped within a DIV? Because the only way I see that happening is wrapping in a div centered align with the buttons A and C floating.

Comment: Well, if your buttons are in their own div, you can float the div anywhere you want, and the buttons will stay together.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about if you put `text-align: center;` on their container and don't float B at all?

(I'm assuming it is an inline element, if not also do `display: inline-block;` on B)

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

> http://jsfiddle.net/UWNTM/1/

Hope it helps.

Basically, I used three wrappers for elements:

```
.button_wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

And then placed button inside them using inline `text-align` property.

Answer (score 1):

try this HTML code:

```
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="right">3</div>
<div class="center">2</div>
```

with this CSS code:

```
.left { float: left; }
.right {float: right; }
.center { margin-left: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:table-cell` for this. Although I think other answers are probably better, it is nice to have alternate solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/bES7Q/

```
<div>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
</div>

div { width: 100%; display: table; }
span {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
}
span:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 99%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with blogger navigation buttons. I've used [xec's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040966/87015) earlier. Here is a variant of the trick I am using right now:

```
.button1, .button2, .button3
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
}
.button1
{
    /* float implies block display */
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/60x20/fc0/000.gif&text=Button+1);
}
.button2
{
    /* set block display to make width, height and auto margin work */
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/60x20/fc0/000.gif&text=Button+2);
}
.button3
{
    /* float implies block display */
    float: right;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/60x20/fc0/000.gif&text=Button+3);
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/HGyC2/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .btn-group{
     margin-top:2%;
     display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
       <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">History</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Expertise</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Differentiators</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Values</button>
       </div>
```

Use the CSS property instead of using margin, padding the above code also suitable for all the button alignment